# Test to compare against a known value

Tags: statistical-significance, mathematical-statistics

I had a set of values of 40 observations, and I want to test their significance different with a known actual value. What test should I carry out in finding out the significance difference?

Comment: Have you tried searching the Internet with phrases like "Statistics compare to a known value?"

Comment: nope, will try it now. thx for your suggestion~!

Comment: For the word "significance" to apply (in the statistical sense), you'd need some null hypothesis (and hopefully an alternative for which you which you would like to have some power), and some assumptions about the situation (do you have independence, for example)?